# Converting a list of dictionaries to models

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List` containing a `Dictionary<string, string>` that represents lines from a database from multiple joined tables. I have tried all sorts of LINQ approaches but I always hit a wall where LINQ just doesn't allow certain operations on this data structure. I have tried to simplify the code example as much as I think I can without misrepresenting the core issue so...

How can I extract explicit `KeyValuePairs` from a `Dictionary` inside of a `List` and put it into a `Model`?

I need a scale-able solution where the `Model` could do the same with the subData.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = GetData();
        data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { ["modelData"] = "Bob", ["subModelData"] = "Frank" });
        data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { ["modelData"] = "Nancy", ["subModelData"] = "Boy" });
        List<Model> models = new List<Model>();
        //Fails in this linq statement. Anonymous types don't allow key accessors
        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> distinctModel in data.GroupBy(x => new { x["dataKey"] }))
        {
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> newModelData = data.Where(d => d["data1Key"] == distinctModel["dataKey"]).ToList();
            Model newModel = new Model(newModelData);
            models.Add(newModel);
        }
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public string modelData;
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> subData;

    public Model(List<Dictionary<string, string>> data) {
        modelData = data[0]["dataKey"];
        data.Remove("dataKey");
        subData = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: `.GroupBy(x => new { x.GetValue("dataKey") })` instead?

Comment: Are you referring to [TryGetValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx)? That is still not a simple name or member access.

Comment: @Thor - Can you please show some sample data? It will make it clearer on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: It's hard to suggest a "scalable" solution given your problem statement.  At first glance your code sample complexity looks sub-optimal.  I.e., if you really want this to run fast you might want to rethink your approach.

Comment: The list can contain 35k+ Dictionaries and each dictionary has the same number of pairs (34) so it's a lot of data. Main problems around this problem statement (trying to limit the scope here) are avoiding duplicates and correctly representing parent <-> child relationships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous type projection initializer should be a simple name or member access. So you need to add an explicit name like below:

```
data.GroupBy(x => new {S = x["dataKey"] })
```

Comment: I'd clarify that if a representing something OTHER than a property directly in an anonymous type projection, an explicit name is required, else the name can be inferred.