# C# Linq - Select Multiple Fields where one field should also be filtered with a select

Tags: c#, linq, nested-lists

I'm a little bit stuck in Linq.

So first - I show you first the entities. I have a List let's name it "PersonalList" with another List of ListMembers.

```
public class PersonalList
{
  public PersonalList();
  public List<ListMember> ListMembers { get; set; }
  public long ListNumber {get; set; }
  public string Description {get; set;}

}
```

Here is the ListMember Class:

```
public class ListMember
{
  public ListMember();
  public string MemberName{ get; set; }
  public long ListId {get; set; }
  public string MemberType {get; set; }
  public string Position {get; set; }
}
```

So now im my AppClass I have a List of the PersonalLists.
And I want to create a Dictionary, which has the PersonalList.ListNumber as Key and the Value should be the MemberName AND the MemberType.

What I have tried in first step is:

```
var personalLists = _allPersonalLists.Select(x => new {x.ListNumber, x.ListMembers).ToArray();
```

This solves the Problem with ListNumbers as Key. Now I want to have the ListMembers to be filtered so I have tried:

```
var personalLists = _allPersonalLists.Select(x => new {x.ListNumber, x.ListMembers.Select(y => new {y.MemberName, y.MemberType})}).ToArray();
```

But here - I get a compile error with following error message:

> Error CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type
>   members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or
>   member access.

So how can I achieve my goal? Any suggestions?

Comment: Use named property to store second `Select` result: `var personalLists = _allPersonalLists.Select(x => new {x.ListNumber, ListMembers = x.ListMembers.Select(y => new {y.MemberName, y.MemberType})}).ToArray();`.

Comment: A method-call is simply not a valid name for an anoynmous types property. Assign its result to a property within your anonymous type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40003900/2946329

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856885/invalid-anonymous-type-member-declarator. Any property that initialized with an expression must have a name to infer expression result.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thank you - this works for me. If you post your answer as an aswer (not as a comment) I would like to accept it as an answer :) I was close to the final solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate your scenario and following solution will work for you.

```
public class PersonalList
{
    public List<ListMember> ListMembers { get; set; }
    public long ListNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ListMember
{
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public long ListId { get; set; }
    public string MemberType { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<PersonalList> _allPersonalLists = new List<PersonalList>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        List<ListMember> ListMembers = new List<ListMember>();
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
            ListMembers.Add(new ListMember() { ListId = j, MemberName = "Member" + i + j, MemberType = "Type" + i, Position = "Position" + i });

        _allPersonalLists.Add(new PersonalList() { ListNumber = i, ListMembers = ListMembers, Description = "Desc" + i });
    }

    var personalLists = _allPersonalLists.ToDictionary(x => x.ListNumber, x => x.ListMembers.Select(y => new { y.MemberName, y.MemberType }).ToList());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var personalLists = _allPersonalLists
                .Select(x => new
                { 
                  x.ListNumber,
                  members = x.ListMembers
                             .Select(y => new 
                                          { 
                                            y.MemberName, 
                                            y.MemberType 
                                          }).ToList() 
                 }).ToArray();

`.ToList()` i included to keep actual values otherwise it will be enumerable
```